# ContinueWith after PostAsJsonAsyc

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I've got a vs2010, 4.0 vb.net, WinForms app calling AttemptLogin on a form load event.
I want to avoid blocking the form load if possible and I was hoping the tasks and continuation stuff in 4.0 would be the right way to go as I could run the main task on the default scheduler and the continuation on fromcurrentsynchronisationcontext but although I've got the OnAttemptLogin working I can't get my OnAttemptLoginCompleted function in the continuation to be called.

I think it's because the OnAttemptLogin returns a "RunToCompletion" task so the continuation never gets called. But I don't know how to deal with that, I've tried numerous things but I've now confused myself so much I'm pretty much mashing keys. Can anyone offer any advice? Am I simply doing it wrong or have I got the wrong idea all together?

Here's what I have so far, the OnAttemptLogin works as I would expect it to, but it then never calls the LongRunning tasks continuation.

Please note: I **can't use await** as I'm in vs2010 .net4.0 so I'm stuck with ContinueWith.

```
Public Sub AttemptLogin(OnAttemptLoginCompleted As Action(Of Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)))
    Try
        Dim LongRunningTask As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                                                        Return OnAttemptLogin()
                                                                                    End Function, TaskScheduler.Default)

        Dim UITask As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = LongRunningTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                                                                                      OnAttemptLoginCompleted(t)
                                                                                  End Sub, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext)
        LongRunningTask.Wait()
    Catch ex As AggregateException
        ' nom nom nom
        ' do something useful
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function OnAttemptLogin() As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim aClient = New HttpClient()
    Using (aClient)
        ' CREATE REQUEST
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", CallingDTO.Email, CallingDTO.Password))))
        UserQueryDTO.UserName = UserDTO.Email
        UserQueryDTO.Password = UserDTO.Password
        Dim url As String = DnnRequest.GetUrl(Credentials.HttpAlias, cstModuleAssembly, "User", "CanLogin", False)

        ' POST REQUEST
        Dim p As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = aClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, UserQueryDTO).ContinueWith(Function(x)
                                                                                                            ' READ RESPONSE
                                                                                                            Dim r = x.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of HttpResponseMessage)()
                                                                                                            r.Wait()
                                                                                                            Return r.Result
                                                                                                        End Function)
        Try
            p.Wait()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Return p

    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is ... convoluted. The main issue you have here, the reason why UITask won't run, is because LongRunningTask is not of type Task(Of HttpResponseMessage). It is actually a Task(Of Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)). OnAttempLogin() returns a Task(of H...), but the task that you start in form load is a Task that will return that Task, hence, Task(Of Task(Of ...)). So there's an exception in that line, hence the UITask line never runs. So the problem with the code is that there's too many Task things all over the place.

The other problem is that you aren't really doing anything asynchronously (except that part that never ran) since you are Wait()-ing for all the tasks. So you need to get rid of most of your waits to actually achieve that. Getting rid of the waits means you need to handle exceptions with a continuation.

Some minor points:

- You don't really need the scheduler stuff, either.
- UITask is simply a Task, not a Task(Of ...) since it doesn't return anything.
- I'm continuing from UITask to handle exceptions so that it also catches UITask's exceptions. If I continued from LongRunningTask, I would miss those exceptions.

Below is an example of what I think the new code will look like. There may be a few syntax issues since I'm missing a few things to get this to compile:

```
Public Sub AttemptLogin(OnAttemptLoginCompleted As Action(Of Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)))
        Dim LongRunningTask As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = OnAttemptLogin()

        Dim UITask As Task = LongRunningTask.ContinueWith(AddressOf OnAttemptLoginCompleted)

        uiTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                                Dim ex As AggregateException = t.Exception
                                'nom nom nom 
                                'all your exceptions will end up here.
                            End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
End Sub

Private Function OnAttemptLogin() As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim aClient = New HttpClient()
    Using (aClient)
        ' CREATE REQUEST
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", CallingDTO.Email, CallingDTO.Password))))
        UserQueryDTO.UserName = UserDTO.Email
        UserQueryDTO.Password = UserDTO.Password
        Dim url As String = DnnRequest.GetUrl(Credentials.HttpAlias, cstModuleAssembly, "User", "CanLogin", False)

        ' POST REQUEST
        Dim p As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = aClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, UserQueryDTO).ContinueWith(Function(x)
                                                                                                            ' READ RESPONSE
                                                                                                            Dim r = x.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of HttpResponseMessage)()
                                                                                                            r.Wait()
                                                                                                            Return r.Result
                                                                                                        End Function)
        Try
            p.Wait()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Return p

    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Sadly this didnt work, the PostAsJsonAsync never happens now (server never receives) and i also get the usual task not observed error...

A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

With inner exception
The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

I know the webapi method is ok as i can call it from Fiddler and with waits etc the call from this code was returning statusCode=ok which is correct for this method/post.

Comment: @Matma That is very strange. I didn't change any of the posting code. Can you look in fiddler to see if the request is actually sent, and if it is different than the request from the original code?

Comment: There is nothing to inspect in fiddler, the error occurs before anything is actually sent. I did a test and uncommentd the wait and the request is sent and is correct.

Comment: @Matma Does your original code still work? Very strange that it wouldn't send out a request anymore.

Comment: Yes, i put it back to how it was and the request is being sent.
There was a minor change required to put it back and that was
return aClient.PostAsJsonAsync should be dim p as Task(of http...) =

Comment: The critical part is "p.wait" as long as i have that it the request is sent.

Comment: @Matma That's sad. If you have the wait, then you're not doing it asynchronously. There must be something else that's conflicting with your code. Does your form immediately close after form_load?

In the mean time, you can use your original OnAttempLogin to make it synchronous. AttemptLogin should be simplified to make it run OnAttemptLoginCompleted. I've updated my answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to delete everything and give up, i will use something else, anything else, pff at this point ill lock the ui and not care, three days on this rubbish is crazy.

Marking jtseng's reply as correct even though it didnt work as hes the only reply and deserves something for taking the time to try and help.